# Why doesn't this javascript work assign .cells[] properly?

Tags: javascript, dom

Why doesn't this work?

```
var row = document.getElementById(currentRow);
var otherRow = document.getElementById(targetRow);
row.cells[0] = otherRow.cells[0];
```

This works with

```
row.cells[0].innerHTML = otherRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
```

However, there are attributes attached to the cell which I also want to move over without having to manually recreate them.

Solution (Note: more is being done in my actual implementation, but this is the framework):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var copyTo = row.cells[i];
    var copyFrom = otherRow.cells[i].cloneNode(true);
    copyTo.parentNode.replaceChild(copyFrom, copyTo);
}
```

Comment: "cells of type HTMLCollection, **readonly**, modified in DOM Level 2" (via http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67349879)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`cloneNode()`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementmethods.shtml) to actually clone the node and its attributes.

Comment: row.cells[0] = otherRow.cells[0].cloneNode(true); does not work.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what exactly did not work there?

Comment: It does not assign the row.cells[0] the new node.  When trying to use .innerHTML on row.cells[0] to see what was passed a DOMElement was passed but row.cells[0] will not accept it as an assignment.

Comment: You might need to use other DOM methods to actually add the node as a child of the table row, then. (Sorry I can't be more help right now, I'm a little pressed for time.)

Comment: I actually managed to solve this problem, with a combination of help including yours.  The solution was to use replaceChild() from the parentNode with a cloneNode(), so thank you for the effort, couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 2):

Each entry in `cells` refers to a DOMElement.  When you typed `row.cells[0] = otherRow.cells[0]`, you are saying that you want `row.cell[0]` to reference the same DOMElement as `otherRow.cells[0]`.

I'm guessing you want `row.cells[0]` to have the same text or HTML as `otherRow.cells[0];` in which case, the second code snippet will do just that, since you are actually modifying the DOMElement, and not just changing which DOMElement you are referencing.

Comment: Thank you for the point about pointers.  The second snippet will not move the attributes over though :(.

Comment: The attributes of the <tr> element, or the attributes of its children?

Comment: How can I make a deep copy of the DOMElement?

Comment: The attributes of the <tr> element (Sorry, misread) EDIT: The attribute of the <td> element, which is the first cell (i.e. cells[0]) of the row.

Comment: You may have to manually copy the attributes of the `<tr>` element over.  `innerHTML` will copy all the html of the `<tr>` element.  I don't think it will copy over event listeners.